# maximize window on document ready with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

That might sound like a stupid one but I can't find anything relevant : how to maximize the window on `document ready` with jquery ? Or any other generic solution that will work fine on all browsers...

Thanks guys ;)

Comment: No. Just **no**. You don't get to resize my windows, I'm in charge of that, thank you very much. Have you any idea just how annoying this 'feature' would be?

Comment: Don't do it at all. It way too annoying.

Comment: Do you want to make the browser window full-screen or make the content of your webpage fill the browser window?

Comment: Sounds like the 90' all over again...

Comment: @DidierG., everything old is new again. Sigh.

Comment: Depending on the amount of facial hair you have and tightness of your jeans, it may just be `retro`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
window.moveTo(0, 0);
window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
```

Comment: That is because it doesn't work :-P @SazzadTusharKhan http://stackoverflow.com/a/8391294/561731 ^_^

Comment: @Neal, no, because [other reasons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.moveTo#Notes).

Answer (score 4):

This is **not possible** for main windows, only for dynamic created windows( created with window.open)

according to:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/moveTo
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/moveBy

Quote:

- You can't resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open.
- You can't resize a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than
  one tab.

The same of for chrome. Haven't checked IE/Safari though.

Answer (score -2):

I found this method. But I can't make it work. Theoretically, it should be possible to change the width and height of the screen, using positive values.

```
window.resizeBy(xDelta, yDelta);
```

For more information, visit http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_resizeby.asp.

Comment: Besides providing (useful) answers, the goal is to provide good advices too. Resizing browser's windows against the user's will is definetely not a good one.

Answer (score -9):

**NO**

**You cannot do this**

Control over the user's browser (minimize, maximize) is for the **user** only.

Comment: Where is the reference? This answer needs a reference. Saying **no, you can't** is not a hard task.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati [here is your reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391255/maximize-window-on-document-ready-with-jquery/#comment-10359131)

Comment: are you kidding me? Just because David thinks that **it might be awful**, do you expect me to accept that?

Comment: To be fair I agree with @SaeedNeamati on that point: 'Because I said so' is a terrible reference...even though I do appreciate the implicit kudos, obviously... =)

Comment: Why don't you delete that answer?