# How can I maximize a window?

Tags: javascript, maximize, maximize-window

I've got this trouble and I was wondering if you can help me. I'm trying to maximize the window without showing any button or toolbar, and I wish it works in as much as possibles browsers.

Now I can get it with IE, but I can't with Chrome. I've been looking for a solution here but I haven't found any question similar (if it's I'm so sorry).

I've read that it could be easy using jQuery but I have no idea. I prefer to do it using JS
Any suggestion or help will be welcome!

I was using this but doesn't work for Chrome
[image]

Comment: Post an example of what you got working in IE please.

Comment: Fullscreen API has good support already: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen. See demo: http://johndyer.name/lab/fullscreenapi/

Comment: I was using this for IE, but it doesn't work on Chrome, at least for me:
<script>
    window.moveTo(0,0);
    if (document.all) {
       top.window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth,screen.availHeight); 
    }
    else if (document.layers||document.getElementById) {
    if (top.window.outerHeight<screen.availHeight||top.window.outerWidth<screen.availWidth){
    top.window.outerHeight = screen.availHeight;
    top.window.outerWidth = screen.availWidth;
    }
    }
     window.focus();
</script>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maximize window on document ready with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391255/maximize-window-on-document-ready-with-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125084/how-to-make-the-window-full-screen-with-javascript-stretching-all-over-the-scre

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is using `window.resizeBy(x, y)` and `window.resizeTo(x, y)`