# How to restore browser to user selected width and height when gets minimized

Tags: javascript, jsp

If jsp gets minimized onload, i want to restore it again through javascript call. Is there any other way for it. It should restore to user-selected height and width. I have tried this function:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function Maximize() {
    window.innerWidth = screen.width;
    window.innerHeight = screen.height;
    window.screenX = 0;
    window.screenY = 0;
    window.moveTo(0, 0);
    window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
    alwaysLowered = false;
}
</script>
```

but it does not restore browser, browser window still remain minimized, when user restores it manually it is maximized to window size and not to size user has selected.

Answer (score 1):

May be this can help [maximize window on document ready with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391255/maximize-window-on-document-ready-with-jquery/8391294#8391294).

Also, this is not a good practise to maximize the browser. User should be the one controlling this aspect.

Posting as answer due to lack of points.

Comment: No I dont want to maximise the window, I want to restore it back as it is minimized.

Answer (score 0):

The function you show is to maximise the window (when the user decides display the window).

The logic for what you want would be more along these lines:

```
var preservedWidth;
var preservedHeight;

function saveScreenSizeBeforeMinimising()
{
   preservedWidth = window.innerWidth;
   preservedHeight = window.innerHeight;
}


function restoreScreenSize()
{
   window.resizeTo(preservedWidth, preservedHeight);
}
```

Obviously you would have to have the correct event handlers for those functions(I'd also suggest refactoring the naming of the functions and variable names to something more appropriate)

Comment: Thnx for the reply, actually this solution is not working for me, browser still gets minimized, I have to click on taskbar and restore it... It happens in IE only and jsp being loaded contains jason data. However, this JS function saves window ht n width properly.. thnx

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, only calling "window.focus();" on jsp body onload, solves all the problem. I need not have to worry about size also...